# из Java не видно наследование в файле в Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть такой метод который сидит в `Java` классе

```
addDelegate(@NonNull AdapterDelegate<T> delegate)
```

то есть я могу ему передать любой обьект который наследует от `AdapterDelegate`

Создаю файл `Kotlin` `TimelineDelegate` который наследует `AbsListItemAdapterDelegate`(это обстрактный класс который наследует от нужного нам `AdapterDelegate`)

Вот он код на `Kotlin`

```
class TimelineDelegate(callback: Callback): 
AbsListItemAdapterDelegate<BaggageTimelineItem, IRootInterface<List<MyObj>>, 
TimelineDelegate.ViewHolder>()
{
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder
{
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun isForViewType(item: IRootInterface<List<MyObj>>, items: 
MutableList<IRootInterface<List<MyObj>>>, position: Int): Boolean
{
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: BaggageTimelineItem, p1: ViewHolder, p2: MutableList<Any>)
{
    TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | 
Settings | File Templates.
}

class ViewHolder(view: View): BaseHolder<List<MyObj>>(view)
{
    override fun onBind(iItem: List<MyObj>?)
    {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use 
File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
}

interface Callback: ClickListener
```

И вот так я это все собираю в кучу

```
addDelegate(new TimelineDelegate(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick()
            {

            }
        }));
```

И получаю ошибку которая говорит, что метод `addDelegate()` собирается получить как параметр обьект типа `AdapterDelegate`, а я ему типо передаю обьект типа `TimelineDelegate`, то есть он не видит, что `TimelineDelegate` наследуют он `AdapterDelegate`.

Когда класс `TimelineDelegate` написан на `Java` то все работает. Я так понимаю, что нужно как то сообщить компилятору, что там есть наследование, чтоб он как то обратил на это внимание.

Что делаю не так?

***EDIT***

Я понял, что проблема в том, что `TimelineDelegate` наследует от `AbsListItemAdapterDelegate` которому нужно передать 3 типа дженериков. И как видно второй тип это интерфейс `IRootInterface<List<MyObj>>` который как видно тоже требует получить тип дженерика `List<MyObj>`.

Так вот разница между джавой и котлин в том, что джава не требует определять тип дженерика который передается сам как тип. То есть можно написать вот так

```
class TimelineDelegate(callback: Callback): 
AbsListItemAdapterDelegate<BaggageTimelineItem, IRootInterface>, 
TimelineDelegate.ViewHolder>()
```

Просто сказать, что второй тип будет `IRootInterface`, котлин же не позволяет этого сделать. И поэтому когда я пытаюсь передать этот обьект как параметр в метод `addDelegate()` он не принимает его, так как он хочет получить параметр типа `AdapterDelegate<IRootInterface>`,  а у меня получается обьект типа `AdapterDelegate<IRootInterface<List<MyObj>>`

Так вот теперь вопрос. Как с этим жить?))